# Error when extracting column indices with dplyr and conditional pipe operator evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr, pipeline, stringr

The following two operations should lead both to the indices of all numeric variables of the mtcars dataset. Nevertheless, the operation which uses the conditional evaluation of the pipe operator for the dataset produces an error. Can anyone explain why?

MWE :

```
data(mtcars)
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)
mtcars %>% {grep(pattern = . %>% select_if(.predicate = is.numeric ) %>% 
                              colnames %>%
                              str_flatten('|'),x = colnames(.))}
```

Output :

> Error in as.vector(x, "character") :
> cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

```
data(mtcars)
require(dplyr)
require(stringr)
grep(pattern = mtcars %>% select_if(.predicate = is.numeric ) %>% 
                                  colnames %>%
                                  str_flatten('|'),x = colnames(mtcars))
```

Delivers the expected output :  `[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11`

Session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.4.0 dplyr_1.0.7  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.7        rstudioapi_0.13   magrittr_2.0.1    tidyselect_1.1.1  munsell_0.5.0     colorspace_1.4-1  R6_2.5.1          rlang_0.4.11.9001 fansi_0.5.0       tools_4.0.5       grid_4.0.5       
[12] gtable_0.3.0      GauPro_0.2.4      utf8_1.2.2        cli_3.0.1         DBI_1.1.0         ellipsis_0.3.2    assertthat_0.2.1  tibble_3.1.5      lifecycle_1.0.1   crayon_1.4.1      purrr_0.3.4      
[23] ggplot2_3.3.5     vctrs_0.3.8       rpart_4.1-15      glue_1.4.2        stringi_1.4.6     compiler_4.0.5    pillar_1.6.4      generics_0.1.0    scales_1.1.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use the pipe with `where` in `select` as `_if/_at` are deprecated

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
mtcars %>% 
 select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
 names %>%
 str_flatten('|') %>%
 grep(x = colnames(mtcars))
```

-output

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

---

As we are using `stringr`, `str_which` would give the same index output as `grep`

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
  names %>%
  str_flatten('|') %>%
  str_which(string = names(mtcars))
```

-output

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

---

In the OP's code, the `.` can be wrapped within `{}`

```
mtcars %>%
   {grep(pattern = {.} %>% 
           select_if(.predicate = is.numeric ) %>% 
           colnames %>%
           str_flatten('|'),x = colnames(.))
    }
```

-output

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Comment: What does `{.}` exactly do to prevent the error?

Comment: @mugdi the issue is that the `.` is not evaluated properly as the data here.  e.g if you do `as.character(. %>% select_if(.predicate = is.numeric) %>% colnames %>% 
+        str_flatten("|"))
Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'` as `grep` does the `as.character` and this returns the error

Comment: Thanks again. Learned something new today!

Comment: So just for clarification. `{.}` promises the evaluation of `.` at all function levels of the pipe?

Comment: @mugdi that is a hacky way to do the evaluation.  In your original code you are doing the evaluation from left to right and then pass the value on the left in `grep` where as in my code, it is always doing the evaluation in left to right i.e. `grep` is at the last step

Comment: Very interesting. I have never seen this before but it's an interesting feature. Nevertheless, the more intuitive  solution to other code examiners (e.g. my future me) is the first one of your answer!